# Are these continued fractions for the "tails" of $\zeta(3)$ and of the Catalan constant known?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta-function, continued-fractions

For polynomials $a=a(x)$ and $b=b(x)$, define the continued fraction $$f(a,b):=a(1)+ \lower 2pt\overset{\infty }{\underset{n=1}{\mathbb{\LARGE K}}}~\dfrac{b(n)}{a(n+1)}=a(1)+\cfrac{b(1)}{a(2) + \cfrac{b(2)}{a(3)+\lower 2pt\ddots } }.$$ Then it is [well known](https://tpiezas.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/continued-fractions-for-zeta2-and-zeta3/) and immediate from [Euler's continued fraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula) that for $r>1$, we have $$\frac1{\zeta(r)}=f\Bigl(x^r+(x-1)^r,-x^{2r}\Bigr),$$ e.g. $$\frac1{\zeta(3)}=1-\cfrac{1^6}{1^3+2^3 - \cfrac{2^6}{2^3+3^3-\lower 2pt\ddots } }.$$
Now I have found numerically a generalization of this for $\zeta(3)$, more precisely, a family of continued fractions with slightly different polynomials $a(x)$ each time, and having as closed forms each "tail" of the $\zeta(3)$ series: for $k\in\mathbb N$, it looks in fact like
$$ \frac1{\displaystyle{ \sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\frac1{j^3}}}=\frac1{\displaystyle{ \zeta(3)-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac1{j^3}}}=  {f\Bigl(x^3+(x-1)^3+2k(k-1)(2x-1),-x^{6}\Bigr)}= {f\Bigl(\bigl[2x-1\bigr]\bigl[x(x-1)+k^2+(k-1)^2\bigr],-x^{6}\Bigr)}.$$
While for $k=1$ this reduces to the entire series $\zeta(3)$ as above, I wonder how to prove this for $k\ge 2$. And very intriguingly, in spite of the simple form (which, once discovered, looks quite straightforward), I haven't yet found if/how this can be generalized to other zeta values at integers, not even for $\zeta(2)$.

**EDIT** (23.07.22) By means of the polygamma identity $$\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\frac1{j^3}=-\frac12\psi^{(2)}(k)$$ or equivalently just using a Hurwitz zeta function with integer shift $k\in\mathbb N$, it appears that the conjectured identity above can be extended to half-integers $k\in\mathbb Z+\frac12$. If we "blow up" the polynomials of the continued fraction to have integer coefficients again, we get, after shifting by $\frac12$ to  $k\in\mathbb N$, the next conjecture for the tail of the "odd $\zeta(3)$ sum": $$ {4~\displaystyle{\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\frac1{(2j-1)^3}}}= {4\left({\displaystyle{ \frac78\zeta(3)-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac1{(2j-1)^3}}}\right)}=\\=\frac1{f\Bigl(2x^3+2(x-1)^3+(4k^2-1)(2x-1),-4x^{6}\Bigr)}= \frac1{f\Bigl(\bigl[2x-1\bigr]\bigl[ x^2+(x-1)^2+4k^2\bigr],-4x^{6}\Bigr)} .$$

**EDIT** (22.06.22). There are very similar CFs not for $\zeta(2)$, but for the tail of the **alternating** sum $\eta(2)$, as mentioned in the comments (even this seems to be still unproven): $$\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j+k}}{j^2}=\frac2{f\Bigl(x^2+(x-1)^2+k(k-1),-x^4\Bigr) }    .$$

**EDIT** (23.07.22) Like for the $\zeta(3)$ sum above, this can also be extended to half-integers after separating even and odd terms and using the [Hurwitz Zeta Function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bj%3Dk%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B%28-1%29%5Ej%7D%7Bj%5E2%7D), where the sum on Wolfram's RHS (dropping the $(-1)^k$ of course) then can be written in terms of the Catalan constant $G$. It appears indeed that for $k\in\mathbb N$ (but surprisingly, not for $k=0$), it is simply the tail of the [Catalan sum $\beta(2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function), which has conjecturally the following continued fraction representation: $$2\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+j}}{(2j+1)^2}=2\left|G-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{(2j+1)^2}\right|=\frac1{f\Bigl(4x^2+4(x-1)^2+4k^2-1 , -16x^{4}\Bigr)}.  $$

Note that the convergence rate of all these continued fractions is about as slow as for $f\Bigl(x^3+(x-1)^3,-x^{6}\Bigr)$.

Comment: These CF are well known and are part of Ap\'ery's work on $\zeta(3)$ although I am not sure he published them. I have a paper in JTNB around 1979 with C. Batut and M. Olivier which probably have them. The ones for $\zeta(2)$ are similar, $f(x^2+(x-1)^2+k^2-k,-x^4)$ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @HenriCohen Interesting! I couldn't locate such a paper on the JTNB site or digizeitschriften.de. Do you have more details? For $\zeta(2)$, I may have failed to find anything because I didn't use high enough precision. It seems like $f(x^2+(x-1)^2+k^2-k,-x^4)$ only yields closed forms for odd $k$, but the pattern is still unclear. Putting $$g(k):=\frac{1}{f(x^2+(x-1)^2+k^2-k,-x^4)}-\left(\zeta(2)-\sum_{j=1}^{k-2}\frac{1}{j^2}\right),$$ I found $g(3)=\frac12, g(5)= \frac{17}{72}, g(7)= \frac{659}{3600}, g(9)= \frac{42137}{352800}$ etc.

Comment: Sorry, I just found the reference: STDN 1979-1980 by Batut-Olivier, Expose 23, the formula you mention for $\zeta(3)$ and mine for $\zeta(2)$ are on page 23-17 and 23-19 (S=Seminaire instead of Journal).

Comment: @HenriCohen Great, I managed to [find it](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44165362). But I see that in the development of $S_n^\prime$ on the bottom of p.23-17, $n$ is fixed while $k$ varies, likewise on p. 23-19. This is just the converse of mine, but certainly there should be a very close relationship anyway.

Comment: @HenriCohen Note that at the end of my question, I had mentioned that these CFs do not have an accelerated convergence, so in fact, the exposé of your colleagues doesn't address them. But it does provide a proof for the closed form of [a different CF](https://mathoverflow.net/a/425112), which had so far been considered unproven!

Comment: @HenriCohen I have looked again at the CF you mentioned in your first comment. And I made the fascinating discovery that it corresponds to the tail of the *alternating sum* $\eta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ rather than to $\zeta(2)$, because we have in fact (supposedly) for odd $k$ $$\frac{1}{f(x^2+(x-1)^2+k^2-k,-x^4)}=\zeta(2)-2\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j^2}=2 \sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j^2} ,$$ while for even $k$ the RHS would be negative.

Comment: In fact, for even $k$, it is still (twice) the tail with the appropriate sign $$\frac{1}{f(x^2+(x-1)^2+k^2-k,-x^4)}=2  \sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j^2} .$$

Comment: please have a look at my new preprint arXiv:2304.11727

Comment: @HenriCohen Nice findings! In fact you have my first one in section 11.1 in your paper where you say "Bauer–Muir acceleration leads to the family $ζ(3) = ((2n − 1)(n^2 − n + 2k^2 +2k + 1), −n^6)$" (for the $A(n)$, your $n$ is $n+1$ in my notation). Similarly the Bauer–Muir transformation of your first family in section 2.1 is my conjecture for the tail of $\eta(2)$. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am very happy to find the "tails" formula of $\zeta(3)$ here. I have discovered the "tails" formula of $\eta(2)$ and $\beta(2)$ (Catalan's constant). You should be able to find these two similar formula from the identities below:
$$
\zeta(2)=2\eta(2)=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{1+\frac{4}{1+\frac{6}{1+\frac{9}{1+\frac{12}{1+\cdots }}}}}}}
$$
$$
\beta(2)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{4}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{6}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{12}{\frac{1}{2}+\cdots}}}}}}}
$$

OEIS A087811 $\left \{1,2,4,6,9,12,16,20,25,30,36,42,49,56,64,72,⋯\right \}$

$a_{k}=k+a_{k-2},  a_0=1,  a_1=2$

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/178860)

Comment: This is a bit different kind of CF, as the numerators are not "exactly" polynomials but composed of two "intermingled" ones. Even though we don't address these, you may be interested at our recent publication https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.11829.pdf

Comment: May you tell me how you came up with these identities? (I mean, with the RHS?)

Comment: Anyway, it gives rise to the more than interesting conjectures
$$ \frac{1}{f((n+1)(2n+3)+k^2,-n(n+1)^3)}=-2k^3\Phi(-1,2,k)+k+1$$
and 
$$ \frac{1}{f((n+1)(2n+1)+k^2,-n^3(n+1))}=2k\Phi(-1,2,k)-\frac{1}{k}$$ where $\displaystyle\Phi(z, s, \alpha) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac { z^n} {(n+\alpha)^s}$ is the Lerch transcendent!