# Finding the continued fraction for the "tails" of $\eta(3)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, continued-fractions, dirichlet-series

I am interested in the continued fractions for the "tails" or "correction term" of the series sum of specific constants. For example, the Madhava's correction term for $\pi/4$:

$$
\frac{\pi}{4}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}+\frac{(-1)^n}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2n+{\overset{\infty }{\underset{k=1}{\Large\vcenter{\hbox{K}}}}~\dfrac{k^2}{2n}}}$$

and the "tails" for $\zeta(2)$:

$$
\zeta(2)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{2}{2n+1+{\overset{\infty }{\underset{k=1}{\Large\vcenter{\hbox{K}}}}~\dfrac{k^4}{(2k+1)(2n+1)}}}$$

[This post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425004/) from [Wolfgang](https://mathoverflow.net/users/29783/wolfgang) shows the continued fraction "tails" for $\zeta(3)$, also discusses the "tails" for $\eta(2)$ and $\beta(2)$ (Catalan's constant). The comment of the post from [Henri Cohen](https://mathoverflow.net/users/81776/henri-cohen) indicates that a [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44165362) (STDN 1979-1980 by Batut-Olivier, Expose 23) had studied this subject and revealed several continued fraction "tails" for the constants like $\pi/4, \ln(2), \eta(2), \zeta(2), \beta(2)$ and $\zeta(3)$. This paper developed a general method to derive such continued fraction "tails" for a series sum. But it's in French and I can't figure out the process how the author derived these continued fractions.

I am trying to find out the continued fraction "tails" for $\eta(3)$ without success. From known facts:

$$
\ln(2)=\eta(1)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}+(-1)^n\cdot \frac{1}{2n+1+{\overset{\infty }{\underset{k=1}{\Large\vcenter{\hbox{K}}}}~\dfrac{k^2}{2n+1}}}$$

$$
\eta(2)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2}+\frac{(-1)^n}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{n(n+1)+1+{\overset{\infty }{\underset{k=1}{\Large\vcenter{\hbox{K}}}}~\dfrac{-k^4}{k^2+(k+1)^2+n(n+1)}}}$$

I **guess** the form of the continued fraction "tails" for $\eta(3)$ could be like:

$$
\eta(3)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^3}+(-1)^n\cdot \frac{1}{n^3+(n+1)^3+a+{\overset{\infty }{\underset{k=1}{\Large\vcenter{\hbox{K}}}}~\dfrac{\pm k^6}{p(k)+n^3+(n+1)^3}}}$$
where $p(k)$ is a polynomial of $k$, maybe of degree 3, and $p(0)=a$.

I worked on this format for several days, but haven't got anything good yet. The correct formula seems more complex than I expect. Does anyone kow this continued fraction "tails" for $\eta(3)$, or know how to derive such formula by referring the paper mentioned above?

Comment: Maybe the $n^3+(n+1)^3$ needs a factor? Inferring from $\eta(2)$, maybe  $\dfrac12$?

Answer (score 4):

Both authors of the paper you mention were students of mine, so I know the paper quite well! The method is called "Apery acceleration" and has been described in several places (if I am allowed some self-advertising, look at Section 7.5 of my joint book with K. Belabas "Numerical algorithms for number theory using Pari/GP", AMS Math surveys and monographs 254). To answer your specific question, we tried very hard in the 1980's to find a CF for the tails of $\eta(3)$ of the form you mention, with no success. I will soon post on the arXiv a much longer explanation of the method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. It's an honor to have your attention on my post. Seems it's very difficult to find the "tails" for $\eta(3)$, or maybe there's no answer for it. I've  established the Laurent sereis for the "tails" of $\eta(3)$, that's how I found the "tails" for $\eta(2)$ and the other constants. To match the first 3 terms of the Laurent series, the first term of the continued fraction would be $2n^3+3n^2+9n/2+7/4$, then there's nothing that can go on for the continued fraction to develop the next term since it's impossible to match the 4th term of the Laurent. series.